# Mesh doesnt change in the viewport while view port shading is in render mode

Tags: 3d-view

I'm sculpting a mesh in the 3d view port with the view port shading in 'render' mode, but the mesh doesn't show any changes I make until I switch to another shading mode. Is there anyway to change this?

Comment: Make sure you didn't pause the viewport,If you are using multires make sure your render level equal the sculpting and the view level.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the update-hook/redraw-hook got lost.
Did you try toggeling edit and objectmode?
If that aint working, I'll try writing a patch.

Comment: Nothing worked except changing to something other than render mode :s

Comment: I'll try some stuff tomorrow